# ubuntu LiveCd enable user login

Tags: 18.04, users, login-screen, live-cd

I am customizing **Ubuntu 18.04** and want to boot from a USB drive. As the LiveCD does automatically log in, I Want to enable user login while booting. Can someone pls help me to enable user login for LiveCd?

Regards

Comment: What tool are you using for customization?

Comment: Not using any tool, but  following steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization article

Comment: Great, you already saw that article. Where are you stuck? Do you get any error message? Is the behaviour different from expected behaviour? Please update your Question with more details.

Comment: I am not getting any errors messages . User(ubuntu user in live cd) has to enter is password to enter the OS as normal OS installed on desktop.